# How we can send some data back to bitbucket server from the Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

Whenever pr is created on bitbucket We've setup our Jenkins and build is triggered automatically. We can see its status(running/failed/success) in our bitbucket repository.

**Now we got requirements that whenever build is failed or successfully built we want to send some data(cope coverage %) to our Bitbucket Server like status.**

Is it possible ? I've searched a lot but didn't find anything.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can uses Code Quality Analysis tools like SonarCloud/SonarQube which takes reports like (Code Coverage, Unit Test, Vulnerability check etc..). You can pass to this from Jenkins.

There is a SonarQube/SonarCloud plugin in bitbucket which you can use to integrate both and see those results in a widget format from bitbucket. Something similar to this.
[image]

Comment: Link/name of the plugin?